# Advanced search with geocoding generates error

Tags: drupal, search, geocoding

I have installed [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) and then installed [Civicrm](https://civicrm.org/) 4.7.19 with the demo data and I have enabled google maps to geo code contacts address.

The problem now when I search using 'address fields' in 'advanced search'

I have added a Postal code and 'Find contacts within'

I always got this message

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

and here is the error details

```
Additional Details:

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => 0
    [message] => 
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => 
    [type] => PEAR_Error
    [user_info] => 
    [to_string] => [pear_error: message="" code=0 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=""]
)


backTrace

#0 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(PEAR_Error))
#2 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(PEAR_Error))
#3 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(577): PEAR_Error->__construct("", 0, 16, (Array:2), NULL)
#4 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(Net_Socket), "", 0)
#5 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:3))
#6 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Net/Socket.php(156): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:2))
#7 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Net/Socket.php(156): Net_Socket->raiseError("", 0)
#8 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTTP/Request.php(737): Net_Socket->connect("ssl://maps.googleapis.com", 443, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#9 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Geocode/Google.php(126): HTTP_Request->sendRequest()
#10 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/ProximityQuery.php(344): CRM_Utils_Geocode_Google::format((Array:4))
#11 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(1992): CRM_Contact_BAO_ProximityQuery::process(Object(CRM_Contact_BAO_Query), (Array:5))
#12 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(2031): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClauseSingle((Array:5), NULL)
#13 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(519): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->whereClause(NULL)
#14 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php(479): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->initialize(NULL)
#15 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Selector.php(237): CRM_Contact_BAO_Query->__construct((Array:7), NULL, NULL, FALSE, FALSE, 1, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, "", "AND")
#16 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search.php(692): CRM_Contact_Selector->__construct(NULL, (Array:46), (Array:7), NULL, 512, FALSE, TRUE, "advanced", (Array:11))
#17 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Advanced.php(45): CRM_Contact_Form_Search->preProcess()
#18 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(543): CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced->preProcess()
#19 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Refresh.php(62): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#20 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Refresh->perform(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced), "refresh")
#21 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contact_Form_Search_Advanced), "refresh")
#22 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("refresh")
#23 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(310): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:4), (Array:0))
#24 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#25 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#26 /var/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#27 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "search", "advanced")
#28 /var/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#29 /var/index.php(26): menu_execute_active_handler()
#30 {main}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! I've amended the title and improved the formatting to try to make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: It looks like the error is related to Google's geocoding service.  Have you tried turning geocoding off to see if you still get an error?

Comment: I have disabled it and not I can see the range to search with but I want to fix the problem to google geocoding service because my task is related to this part

Comment: If I understand you correctly there isn't an error if you disable geocoding.  So it sounds like this is an issue with the connection to Google's geocoding service.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it ? because I can't find the real cause of the error.

Comment: Sorry, it's not an area I have experience with.  I'm hoping someone else can make a suggestion here.

Comment: I know how to solve it but I don't know the exact error, or where I can find it